# Results output to txt file by group

Tags: powershell

I'm currently studying Powershell and working on a script that grabs multi-monitors Display configuration from windows system. Thanks to the help from other guys, I finally work out a full script to show each monitor's resolution, Video output category, Manufacturer, and Model. Here is the full script:

```
add-type -assemblyName system.windows.forms 
[system.windows.forms.screen]::AllScreens.Bounds | format-list Width,Height | 
out-file -append system1.txt

enum VideoOutputTechnology {
UNINITIALIZED                    = -2
UNKNOW                           = -1
VGA                              = 0
S_VIDEO                          = 1
COMPOSITE_VIDEO                  = 2
COMPONENT_VIDEO                  = 3
DVI                              = 4
HDMI                             = 5
LVDS_OR_MIPI_DSI                 = 6
D_JPN                            = 8
SDI                              = 9
DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL             = 10
DISPLAYPORT_EMBEDDED             = 11
UDI_EXTERNAL                     = 12
UDI_EMBEDDED                     = 13
DONGLE_CABLE_THAT_SUPPORTS_SDTV  = 14
MIRACAST_CONNECTED_SESSION       = 15
INTERNAL_CONNECTION              = 0x80000000
}
Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorconnectionparams -Namespace root\wmi | 
Format-List @{ 
n='VideoOutputTechnology'
e={ [VideoOutputTechnology] $_.VideoOutputTechnology } 
} >> system1.txt

Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi | ForEach-Object {
 [PSCustomObject]@{
     Manufacturer = ($_.ManufacturerName | ForEach {[char]$_}) -join ""
     Model        = ($_.UserFriendlyName | ForEach {[char]$_}) -join ""
 }
} | Format-List | Out-File -append system1.txt
```

The output in system1.txt is:

```
Width  : 1920
Height : 1080

Width  : 2560
Height : 1440





VideoOutputTechnology : DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL

VideoOutputTechnology : DVI





Manufacturer : ACI             
Model        : ASUS PB287Q  

Manufacturer : SAM             
Model        : SMS27A850
```

My question is: How could I make the output results group by each monitor.
For example:

```
Manufacturer: ACI             
Model: ASUS PB287Q  
Width: 1920
Height: 1080
VideoOutputTechnology: DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL

Manufacturer: SAM             
Model: SMS27A850    
Width: 2560
Height: 1440
VideoOutputTechnology: DVI
```

Thanks in advance for everyone's reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the partial results into variables and assemble all in one [PSCustomObject]
(I'm not quite sure if the order of the screens will match the MonitorID order)
The property `InstanceName` which is common to both `WmiMonitorID` and `WmiMonitorconnectionparams` is used to sync the settings.

**EDIT: incorporated [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368476/results-output-to-txt-file-by-group/51369218?noredirect=1#comment89711030_51369218)'s hint**
**EDIT2: added properties ProductCodeID,SerialNumberID,Manufactured(year,week)**

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\16\SO_51368476.ps1
## 

enum VideoOutputTechnology {
UNINITIALIZED                    = -2
UNKNOW                           = -1
VGA                              = 0
S_VIDEO                          = 1
COMPOSITE_VIDEO                  = 2
COMPONENT_VIDEO                  = 3
DVI                              = 4
HDMI                             = 5
LVDS_OR_MIPI_DSI                 = 6
D_JPN                            = 8
SDI                              = 9
DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL             = 10
DISPLAYPORT_EMBEDDED             = 11
UDI_EXTERNAL                     = 12
UDI_EMBEDDED                     = 13
DONGLE_CABLE_THAT_SUPPORTS_SDTV  = 14
MIRACAST_CONNECTED_SESSION       = 15
INTERNAL_CONNECTION              = 0x80000000
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms
$Screens = [system.windows.forms.screen]::AllScreens.Bounds

$MIDs = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi

$i=0
$AllMonInfo = ForEach ($MID in $MIDs){
    $MCP = (Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorconnectionparams -Namespace root\wmi |
        Where-Object InstanceName -eq $MID.InstanceName)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Manufacturer = (-join [char[]] $MID.ManufacturerName)
        Model        = (-join [char[]] $MID.UserFriendlyName)
        ProductCodeID= (-join [char[]] $MID.ProductCodeID)
        SerialNumberID=(-join [char[]] $MID.SerialNumberID)
        Manufactured = ("{0}W{1}" -f $MID.YearOfManufacture,$Mid.WeekOfManufacture.ToString('00'))
        Width        = $Screens[$i].Width
        Height       = $Screens[$i].Height
        VideoOutput  = ([VideoOutputTechnology]$MCP.VideoOutputTechnology)
    }
    $i++
} 

$AllMonInfo | Format-List | Out-File '.\system1.txt' -Append -Encoding ascii
```

Sample output:

```
Get-Content '.\system1.txt'

Manufacturer   : SAM
Model          : SyncMaster
ProductCodeID  : 03E7
SerialNumberID : H9XQxxxxxx
Manufactured   : 2008W40
Width          : 1920
Height         : 1200
VideoOutput    : DVI

Manufacturer   : SAM
Model          : SyncMaster
ProductCodeID  : 0425
SerialNumberID : H1AKxxxxxx
Manufactured   : 2008W10
Width          : 1920
Height         : 1200
VideoOutput    : DVI
```