# Merging/Joining two results from 2 different foreach loops

Tags: powershell

Received a serious assist yesterday from mklement0

But as I continue working on the script, I have run into another issue that I have researched and worked on for the better part of 2 days.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Monitors = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens

foreach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
{
    $connections = get-ciminstance -namespace root/wmi -classname WmiMonitorConnectionParams
    $videooutput = $connections.VideoOutputTechnology
    $DeviceName = (($Monitor.DeviceName).replace("\", "")).replace(".", "")
    $Width = $Monitor.bounds.Width
    $Height = $Monitor.bounds.Height

    Foreach ($type in $videooutput){
        switch ($videooutput) {
            10 { $type = "DP"; break}
            4  { $type = "DVI"; break}
            5  { $type = "HDMI"; break}
            0  { $type = "VGA"; break}
            default { "unknown"}
        }
    }
    Write-Host "$DeviceName - $Width x $height - $Type"
}
```

The answer I get is this:

```
DISPLAY1 - 1920 x 1080 - DVI
DISPLAY2 - 1920 x 1080 - DVI
```

The answer should be:

```
DISPLAY1 - 1920 x 1080 - DVI
DISPLAY2 - 1920 x 1080 - DP
```

Comment: This will not work how you expect it to. `$connections.VideoOutputTechnology` returns an array of all monitor connections. So in your case `$(10,4)`. When you run the  `foreach ($Type in $videooutput)` it will return the last item in the array as `$type` which is 4. Thats why you get DVI on both. Honestly the way you have it wont ever be 100% accurate due to the way you engineered it. If you are OK with just having whatever monitor list whatever connectiontype Then i can fix it as it currently is.

Comment: Can it be assumed that the arrays resulting from `AllScreens` and `WmiMonitorConnectionParams` are in the same order? The VideoOutputTechnology is already in the `$connections` object, so it probably does not need to be taken out separately.

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368476) (and use the more detailed enum for the videooutput technology)

Comment: Thank for all the feedback,  I thought I had painted myself in to a corner with my code.  I haven't done anything with PSCustomObject, I see from the other solution it is something I need to read up on.