# Why is ManufacturerName and UserFriendlyName incomplete?

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

Running this script:

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit =-1
Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$LogFile = "C:\Users\monkeygead\Desktop\monitors.txt"

"Manufacturer,Name,Serial"

ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
{
    $Manufacturer = ($Monitor.ManufacturerName -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $Name = ($Monitor.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $Serial = ($Monitor.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""

    "$Manufacturer,$Name,$Serial"
}
```

It's outputting:

> DEL,DELL U415,CV9N64604TL
>   DEL,DELL U415,CV9N81S1C6S

Why is manufacturer reported as DEL and not DELL, and the model number is reported as DELL U415 and not DELL U2415?

Comment: the storage in  the monitor ROM is SMALL. very, very, very small. [*grin*] so you will find only what they had room for - with priority given to the SN.

Answer (score 1):

With your code I get also partially crippled data,

```
SAM,SycMastr,H9XQ900000
SAM,SycMastr,H1AK500000
```

not so with mine from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51369218/6811411)

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit =-1
Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$LogFile = Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) "monitors.csv"

$Data = ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors){
   [PSCustomObject]@{
           Manufacturer = (-join [char[]] $Monitor.ManufacturerName)
           Name         = (-join [char[]] $Monitor.UserFriendlyName)
           Serial       = (-join [char[]] $Monitor.SerialNumberID)
    }
}

$Data
# $Data | Out-Gridview
# $Data | Export-Csv $LogFile -NoTypeInformation
```

---

```
Manufacturer     Name          Serial
------------     ----          ------
SAM              SyncMaster    H9XQ000000
SAM              SyncMaster    H1AK500000
```